# I am not able to post questions from many days?

Tags: support

I understand , I have posted many questions that have been down voted . But there are questions which have been upvoted also like this one [What pleasure does God get from the creation of humans?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/45288/what-pleasure-does-god-get-from-the-creation-of-humans)

I am not able post questions now , even after banning from so many days  ?

After how many days this ban will be removed ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is answered in the help centre: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans

Basically, the ban will be lifted automatically if you improve your old questions.